# Node made on label and not position tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

My question might be really dumb, I'm new with tikz, and I might not understand well the difference between a draw and a node
Here is my picture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin,ball color=red] (0,0) circle(0.4ex) node(mX1){};
\draw[thin,ball color=white] (1,1)  circle(0.4ex) node[left] (X1){$X_1$};
\draw (X1)--(mX1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like a link between my points, and not between the labels. I can't understand why the link is made on labels. My solution was this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,ball color=red!50] (0,0) circle(0.4ex) node(mX1){};
\draw[thin,ball color=white,label=X1] (1,1)  circle(0.4ex) node{$X_1$};
\draw (X1)--(mX1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But here again, the link is made quite tangely (for me)
Does anybody has any solution (and an explanation of what I missed)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not making points with the `(mX1)` you are naming a node. If you just want to name the point, use `coordinate (mX1)`. Also note that you can easily draw from the center of the node, just use `mX1.center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like the right figure below, left and middle figure are the result form your codes.

[image]

Command `\draw` just draws a path between provided coordinates, but it doesn't creates any labels for further reference. You need `node` or `coordinate` (an special kind of `node`) to assign labels to certain points on your canvas which can be later on used to draw lines between them or place new elements.

Your first command

```
\draw[thin,ball color=red] (0,0) circle(0.4ex) node(mX1){};
```

draw a red ball on coordinate (0,0) and also `draws` an invisible and empty node named `mX1` on same coordinate. Change `node (mX1) {}` to `node[draw] (mX1) {}` to make it visible.

Second command

```
\draw[thin,ball color=white] (1,1)  circle(0.4ex) node[left] (X1){$X_1$};
```

does something similar, it draw a white ball on `(1,1)` but a node called `X1` is placed to the left (1cm by default) of `(1,1)`.

Line `\draw (X1)--(mX1);` goes form `X1` border to `mX1` border. And although `X1` node is at origin, `mX1` is not on white ball center, but to the left of it.

Proposed solution

```
\node[circle, very thin, ball color=red!50, minimum size=0.8ex, inner sep=0pt] (mX1) at (0,0) {};
\node[circle, very thin, ball color=white!50, minimum size=0.8ex, label=left:$X_1$, inner sep=0pt] (X1) at (1,1) {};
```

draws balls as circular nodes. This way `X1` and `mX1` make reference to balls center. And label `X_1` is set as a `label` of second node. `minimum size=0.8ex` fixes ball diamenter if `inner sep=0pt`. This way line between nodes borders shows no separation from them.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\draw[thin,ball color=red] (0,0) circle(0.4ex) node(mX1){};
\draw[thin,ball color=white] (1,1)  circle(0.4ex) node[left] (X1){$X_1$};
\draw (X1)--(mX1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\draw[very thin,ball color=red!50] (0,0) circle(0.4ex) node(mX1){};
\draw[thin,ball color=white,label=X1] (1,1)  circle(0.4ex) node{$X_1$};
\draw (X1)--(mX1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\node[circle, very thin, ball color=red!50, minimum size=0.8ex, inner sep=0pt] (mX1) at (0,0) {};
\node[circle, very thin, ball color=white!50, minimum size=0.8ex, label=left:$X_1$, inner sep=0pt] (X1) at (1,1) {};
\draw (X1)--(mX1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

[image: Result of the snippet below]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    point/.style={circle, draw, thin, inner sep=0.4ex}
]
    \node[point, ball color=red,   label=left:$mX_1$] (mX1) at (0, 0) {};
    \node[point, ball color=white, label=left:$X_1$]   (X1) at (1, 1) {};
    \draw (X1)--(mX1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Rather than drawing a circle manually with `circle (0.4ex)`, I created a node shaped like a circle. The `point` style says that such a node should have its outline `draw`n, using a `thin` line. (In general, if you `\draw` something, it means "draw the outline of the stuff on this path".) It should be shaped like a `circle`, and have an `inner sep` (padding) of 0.4ex. Because this node doesn't have any text inside it, this padding acts like the radius.

Rather than create the labels manually using `node [left] {$X_1$}`, I used the `label=...` key to specify where and what I want the label to be. This stops me from accidentally calling my label `(X1)` instead of the circle `(X1)`.